# Can I use an AntiForgeryToken without AcceptVerbs tag?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

I would like to use the AntiForgeryToken function but the AcceptVerbs post does not apply.  I am getting the anti forgery error.  Is there a way to do this without the post method?

```
public ActionResult Page1(string data)
{   //code with view that includes link to Edit   }

public ActionResult Page2(string data)
{   //code with view that includes link to Edit   }

public ActionResult Edit(string pageName)
{   //execution then redirect to Page1/Page2  }
```

Comment: Related: Using AntiForgeryToken to prevent JSON CSRF attack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914994/using-mvc3s-antiforgerytoken-in-http-get-to-avoid-javascript-csrf-vulnerability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anti forgery token works by a cookie and a hidden input field in the form. They both hold the same encrypted value. When the controller handles an action decorated with `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` it checks if the values in the cookie and the hidden input field match. If they don't - you get a nice exception.

You can use code like this

View:

```
<% using (var form = Html.BeginForm("DoSomething", "Default")) {  %>
<%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x) %>
<%:Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
<%:Html.Hidden("a", 200) %>
<input type="submit" value="Go"/>
<%}%>
```

Controller:

```
public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DoSomething(int a)
    {
        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

But then the form generated gets an `method="post"` attribute. On the controller side you don't need to specify `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]`. So the answer to your question is that you can use AntiForgeryToken without the AcceptVerbs attribute. You just need to use the POST method in the form.

To continue with the sample, if you specify `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]` on the action and `Html.BeginForm("DoSomething", "Default", FormMethod.Get)`, the example won't work, because the GET request does not contain the cookie only the hidden input value gets encoded in the query string.

Comment: a good idea is to follow the rule that changing the model should be done through post and showing data through get. +1 for answer

Comment: would be interested in seeing your comments on how to protect against JSON CSRF attack mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914994/using-mvc3s-antiforgerytoken-in-http-get-to-avoid-javascript-csrf-vulnerability