# Is it possible to use the MVC3 AntiForgeryToken from a non-MVC3 client (and use it in a SignalR hub)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, signalr, antiforgerytoken

With SignalR, in my web app, I am invoking server-side methods from the client using JavaScript.  The Hub is in a MVC3 project, and the client calls are made from a classic ASP application (since it's JS that's making the calls, it could be any other framework).

If I add the System.Web.MVC namespace and decorate my hub methods with [ValidateAntiForgeryToken], how can I use an anti-forgery token generated by the server (similar to what I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677933/using-the-mvc3-antiforgerytoken-with-links)) and pass it along with client requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the 2 system don't talk to each other that way. None of the mvc pipeline runs when you call into signalr. You'll have to run do manual verification to make that work.